# ffmpeg : Convert all mp4 files in a folder into mp3 in a new folder

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert all my mp4 files in a folder into mp3 in a new folder
I've tried something like:

```
$ffmpeg -i \*.mp4 -vn mp3/\*.mp3
```

but it didn't work. It involved an infinite loop and my computer didn't respond anymore. Any solution ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -f mp3 -ab 192k -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 aud/"${i%.*}.mp3"; done
```

- vn: disable video recording during the conversion.
- ar: set audio sampling rate in Hz.
- ab: set the audio bitrate.
- ac: set the number of audio channels.
- -f: format.
- aud: name of the audio folder